# JavaScript pass mouseenter event to element that is underneath another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api, z-index, jquery-events

I'm trying to build a little calendar app sort of like Google Calendar.  I'm trying to create events with a click and drag functionality so that the events align to a grid.  I'm trying to
tie the dragging to TD elements below the event DIV element, which works when moving downwards (lengthening the event), but it doesn't work moving upwards (shrinking the event).

What occurs is that the `mouseenter` event is fired for the event DIV element, but it is never fired for the underlying TD.  If you try to resize the DIV by moving upwards on the side, it works because the TDs actually receive the `mouseenter` event.

Google Calendar and jQuery Week Calendar use the `mousemove` event, but the `mousemove` event is fired for every pixel, which seems a waste.  Is there a way to write this without using the `mousemove` event?

Is it possible to put the DIV element behind the table and the TDs?  If the table is somewhat transparent, the user would still be able to see the DIV, but would actually be firing events on the TDs.  I tried to do this with `z-index`, but it didn't seem to actually work.

jsFiddle example code: http://jsfiddle.net/rockymeza/8SHpA/

Comment: When I get frustrated with event-normalization I just pull out my standard library of functions and events that I call `jQuery`.

Comment: @zzzBov I don't think you understood my question, I am actually using jQuery.  This isn't a cross browser normalization bug that I'm running into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're having a similar kind of issue that I had:

you want to fire event behind an element? The answer is CSS. Set pointer-events:none; to the parent.

I had made a test where I tried to (unsuccessfully) implement the same behavior on touch devices. You can check that at: http://www.hakoniemi.net/misc/pointer-events.html if it'd help you with your issue.

Comment: Thanks @zvona, if I didn't need to support IE, I would use `pointer-events`.  Instead I went with `z-index: -1`.  I thought I could use `z-index: 2` on the table and `z-index: 1` on the div, but I guess that doesn't work.  A negative `z-index` seems to work for me.