# How to Make an Image Linkable when there is Text with Link Ontop

Tags: html, css

My project requirements has changed from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907384/how-to-make-an-image-with-text-button-on-top-linkable).

I now have a div that contains an image, and content (text with a link) overlayed ontop. The content has the same dimensions as the image. My problem now is that I cannot click on the link assigned to the image. I believe this is because the content is hiding background link.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mjne/1/

HTML

```
<div class="ad">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/320/200">
    <a href="#">  
        <div class="content">
             text
             <a class="link" href="">link</a>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ad {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
}
.link {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('.link').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
    $('.content').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('.link').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $('a').click(function() {
        console.log('a clicked');
    });
    $('.link').click(function() {
        console.log('button clicked');
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** There are two different links in my module. One link is from the background image, and the other link is from the `a` tag found in `.class`.

Comment: When you mention that the text area is the same size of the image, do they have to be that way? is the whole area of the text on top of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution which sort of works. The only issue I have is that is you mouse over the text area to the left of 'meow' and below the word 'my', you will notice you are still in the region of the text link instead of the background link. This is because the text link still has jurisdiction over this space. I am trying to figure out how to get rid of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/WHpMr/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your link isn't assigned to the image...move your opening tag before the `img`:

```
<div class="ad">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/320/200" />                
        <div class="content">              
            text              
            <a class="link" href="#">link</a>        
        </div>     
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: That was my original attempt, but it did not work. My assumption is because `.content` is on a z-index above the img, I should put the link over `.content` since it also visually appears to be the image.

Comment: @icu222much - works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2mjne/2/  -- I can click the image's link as well as the text link...if you want other functionality, please revise your question

Comment: Just a note, <a> can't be parent of <div>.

Comment: I updated my question. I saw your fiddle, and noticed that I can only click on the link that is listed inside `.content`. I cannot click on the link that is outside `.content`.

Comment: @user1734651 Is this part of the specifications?

Comment: @icu222much - I'm still not seeing the issue - in my fiddle, there are two links I can click - one for the image (the first <a> tag) and a second for your mouseover link on the text in the upper-left corner (second <a> with a class of "link") - both are working for me.

Comment: @Jim Sorry, I still do not see the first link for the image. I have tested in Chrome/FF. From what I see, the first link is activated only when you mouse over the word "text", and the very bottom of the image. I wanted the first link to be activated whenever you mouse over any part of the image except for the word "link".

Comment: @icu222much - I was able to re-create the issue using FF...I'll see if I can come up with a solution when I get home tonight

Comment: @Jim Great, thank you. I've spent all day yesterday trying to come up with a solution. What browser were you using previously?

Comment: @Jim I have continued my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924560/text-link-is-hiding-my-image-link

Answer (score 0):

If the text area on top of the image is the same size as the image, the mouse can't reach the image and so, that link doesn't exist for the user/mouse combination.

Also, remember that the user don't expect the link to change in the empty space between words, so the text link should work as expected.

So your solution can be something like this:

Detect the click of the mouse and when pressed, present the user with two options, one for each destination, plus a brief and clear explanation. Is an uncommon way, but it will work.

Present some kind of legend in the page, mentioning all the hidden links and the keyboard access. You can use the accesskey attribute and JS to make that work.

Bye