# Text Link is Hiding my Image Link

Tags: html, css

I have a image where text/link is overlayed on top. My problem is that sometimes the text in the foreground will hide the link in the image in the background. I assume this is because the text box forms an invisible rectangle around the text, thus creating a region that appears it should belong to the image but is actually being covered by the text. I am wondering if it is possible that when I mouse over this region, I will be linking to my image link as oppose to my text link (see illustration).

http://jsfiddle.net/WHpMr/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i.e. put your  tag inside : http://jsfiddle.net/WHpMr/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="ad">
    <span class="link middle right"><a href="#text" class="inline-link">my text link abcdefg<br>meow<br>meow<br>meow</a></span>
    <a href="#background"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/320/200"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ad {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
}
.link {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.inline-link {
    pointer-events: all;
}
.top { top:0%; }
.middle { top:33%; }
.bottom { top:66%; }
.left { text-align:left; left:0%; }
.center { text-align:center; margin:0 auto; width:100%; }
.right { text-align:right; right:0%; }
```

Comment: That still doesn't let the background link work through the 'empty' part of the text box.

Comment: @skovalyov Agreed, the background link still does not work on the 'empty' part of the text link.

Comment: Never heard of `pointer-events`. Pretty interesting stuff. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about browser adoption though. Maybe IE will need its own hack. As usual. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that. The element will create a block containing the content. You could use the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map) Element if you are hell bent on doing that.

Comment: This module will be dynamically generated, each time with a different image size. Before I start playing with `map`, are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

If you make each line its own link, that will minimize the problem.  If you really want to go all out, you can make each word its own link.  But you're getting into stuff that's easier to do with some JS automation instead of manually in the HTML.

**EDIT:** Here's an attempt at a vanilla JS solution that works for your simple example, at least:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLN2d/35/

Comment: That is a very simple solution, but it will be hard to position several lines of text (I will have several lines, I just did not include them on the fiddle).